# How to update time using JS client side

Tags: php, javascript

I want to update the time shown on the records li or divs on a page. 
I have put the time of creation of this record in a hidden field with each record.

example:

```
# Hi what are you doing? 
  5 minute ago.  <hidden id='1' value='1345888475'>

# Akon song is good 
  10 minute ago  <hidden id='2' value='1345888855'>

# I love the way you lie
  15 minute ago <hidden id='3' value='1345889995'>
```

How can I update that time each minute? So after one minute the first div should say 6 minute ago
and second would say 11 minute ago?

Is that possible using JS. I dont want to go php for this. Just using JS. 
Time in DB is stored like `strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))`

Thank you!

Comment: You mean _minute_ right?

Comment: You just want to show minute ago? or days, hours, etc too?

Comment: @TomWalters Obviously nope, he's cooking while programming, and he needs something fresh to eat.

Comment: @OP: the method  you're looking for is `window.setInterval()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Hey, its the apocalypse, gotta fit everything in!

Comment: Programming with mint. That's holiday cheer.

Comment: Darn, now if I go and edit all the "mints" to "minutes" to clarify the question it will ruin this comment thread.

Comment: I thought to go for mintues and hours first, But obviously time can be a date few days ago or a year. But right now i want to update only for records which has few mintues or hours ago. Thought that would be easy for these

Comment: @pjmorse Don't worry, took a screenshot :P

Comment: Yes you can but you'll have to get some parse date to string js libraries

Comment: Not an answer, but it might be easier to pull this off if you used a data attribute on a span rather than a hidden form element, i.e. `<span class="time_since" data-value="1345889995">15 mint ago</span>`.

Comment: hey, I know I need setInterval but I am not good with date time of JS so I need how to add time in it you know :)

Comment: @H2CO3 thread's worth more than the question.

Comment: I'm risking getting a ban, but I had to put a new tag there...

Comment: @pjmorse sorry about that. Yes I can do this and add it to span. Yes

Comment: **Mint**
Mentha is a genus of flowering plants in the family Lamiaceae. The species are not clearly distinct and estimates of the number of species varies from 13 to 18. Hybridization between some of the species occurs naturally

Comment: and A **minute** is a unit of measurement of time or of angle. The minute is a unit of time equal to 1/60 (the first sexagesimal fraction[1]) of an hour or 60 seconds. In the UTC time standard, a minute on rare occasions has 59 or 61 seconds; see leap second. The minute is not an SI unit; however, it is accepted for use with SI units.[2] The SI symbol for minute or minutes is min (for time measurement) or the prime symbol after a number, e.g. 5′ (for angle measurement, even if it is informally used for time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd use HTML like this:

```
<span data-time="1345888475">Loading...</span>
```

Then in your script have something like:

```
(function() {
  var timetostring(secs) {
      if( secs < 60) return secs+" seconds ago";
      secs = Math.floor(secs/60);
      if( secs < 60) return secs+" minutes ago";
      secs = Math.floor(secs/60);
      if( secs < 24) return secs+" hours ago";
      secs = Math.floor(secs/24);
      return secs+" days"; // you can of course continue
  };
  (function() {
      var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("[data-time]"), l = qsa.length, i, t;
      for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
          t = new Date().getTime()/1000-qsa[i].getAttribute("data-time");
          qsa[i].firstChild.nodeValue = timetostring(t);
      }
      setTimeout(arguments.callee,15000);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) that is perfect and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) which is a wonderfull and very lightweight library for everything related to time management in Javascript. The API is very clear, well documented and powerfull.
I am using it for one of my projects, and i am very satisfied so far.

You can use time automatic update handlers which is exactly what you want, very easily with something like the examples below :

> moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // a year ago
>
> moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 6 months ago
>
> moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 19 hours ago
>
> moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 5 hours

To make the time refreshes itself, you can call these functions whithin a `setInterval` handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in JS, you need a few parts:

1. Identify the parts that need to change and give their creation time
2. A timer that updates the times every minute, you'll need php to tell js what time it has
3. A script that transforms the times into readable text at page load.

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/srKET/

```
    <div class="message" id='1' data-timestamp='1345888475'>
    <span class="content"># Hi what are you doing? </span><br/>
    <span class="timeAgo">5 mint ago. </span>
    </div>

    var currentTime = <?=time()?>;
    var timestampHandler = setInterval(onUpdateTimestamp, 60 * 1000); //one minute
    function onUpdateTimestamp(){
         currentTime += 60;
         $(".message").each(updateTimeAgo);
    }

    function updateTimeAgo(){
        var $el = $(this);
        var postTime = parseInt($el.data('timestamp'));
        var newTimeAgo = (currentTime - postTime) / 60; //minutes
        $el.find(".timeAgo").html(newTimeAgo + " mint ago.")
    }
```